# Katetov - KC and sequental spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

A space is said to be KC – space  if compact  subsets are closed.
A KC space  (X,τ) is said to be Katetov – KC if there is a minimal KC – topology σ ⊆ τ.
is every sequential KC - space Katetov - KC?
I know that  every KC space is not  Katetov - KC. do you have any example to show it?

Comment: I wish there would be less of a tongue twister (mind twister)?

Answer (score 4):

It was shown in *"The FDS-property and spaces in which compact sets are closed"* (2004) by Alas, Tkachenko, Tkachuk and Wilson that every sequential KC-space is Katetov-KC (see Corollary 2.6).

The fact that not every KC-space is Katetov-KC was shown by Fleissner in *"A $T_B$-space which is not Katetov $T_B$"* (1980).

Comment: I read the whole article but I did not understand which part was exactly ma answer.